# Allow page to grow with content using a bottom positioned footer

Tags: html, css

I have used this tutorial (http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) to design a site with a footer that floats at the bottom of my screen regardless of the length of content - however the problem I now have is when there is more content that will display in the viewport, not less.

My design is more complicated than the one he demos and I'm using this with a CMS, so it's obviously a little different in terms of the html.

Does anyone have any tricks for pushing down content when using this model - the site I'm working on is http://sproffer.joyatechsolutions.com

If you go to the pricing page - you'll see that there is more content than displays (5 paragraphs) and although the scrollbar displays - it only adds space below the footer that is supposed to be stationary at the bottom.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using

```
position:fixed;
```

for the #bottom

you should also add a padding-bottom on the #mainContent of

```
padding-bottom: 255px;
```

This is to stop the content of #mainContent being hidden by the #bottom div

Infact looking at it i would change your div#mainContent to

```
div#mainContent {
    width: 1000px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 225px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked perfectly and I'll try a variation on another site with a similar issue.